# Secure Websockets in php - how to add certificate to script

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, wss

I'm trying to understand websockets. I have found excelent example on https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/.

But got stuck implementing certificate to use it on wss. The example is based on socket_create() but to socket_set_option() certificate doesnt fit and i din't find how to combine that with stream_context_set_option() or stream_sockte_.... Is socket part of a stream? Am I missing something else.

Sorry not experienced in websockets nor ssl connection... I have googled for almost 2, days and not moved forward... Thank you for anything, that shifts me forward...

how can I combine

```
define('HOST_NAME',"localhost"); 
define('PORT',"8090");
$null = NULL;

require_once("class.chathandler.php");
$chatHandler = new ChatHandler();

$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socketResource);


//with 

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
      'local_cert'=>'/usr/local/etc/apache224/ssl.crt/www.mojehra.cz.crt',
      'local_pk'=>'/usr/local/etc/apache224/ssl.key/www.mojehra.cz.key'
    )
  );
  
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

The full original example is below.

```
<?php
define('HOST_NAME',"localhost"); 
define('PORT',"8090");
$null = NULL;

require_once("class.chathandler.php");
$chatHandler = new ChatHandler();

$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socketResource);

$clientSocketArray = array($socketResource);
while (true) {
    $newSocketArray = $clientSocketArray;
    socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);
    
    if (in_array($socketResource, $newSocketArray)) {
        $newSocket = socket_accept($socketResource);
        $clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;
        
        $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
        $chatHandler->doHandshake($header, $newSocket, HOST_NAME, PORT);
        
        socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
        $connectionACK = $chatHandler->newConnectionACK($client_ip_address);
        
        $chatHandler->send($connectionACK);
        
        $newSocketIndex = array_search($socketResource, $newSocketArray);
        unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);
    }
    
    foreach ($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {  
        while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1){
            $socketMessage = $chatHandler->unseal($socketData);
            $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage);
            
            $chat_box_message = $chatHandler->createChatBoxMessage($messageObj->chat_user, $messageObj->chat_message);
            $chatHandler->send($chat_box_message);
            break 2;
        }
        
        $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($socketData === false) { 
            socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
            $connectionACK = $chatHandler->connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address);
            $chatHandler->send($connectionACK);
            $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clientSocketArray);
            unset($clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);         
        }
    }
}
socket_close($socketResource);
?>
```

class

```
<?php
class ChatHandler {
    function send($message) {
        global $clientSocketArray;
        $messageLength = strlen($message);
        foreach($clientSocketArray as $clientSocket)
        {
            @socket_write($clientSocket,$message,$messageLength);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function unseal($socketData) {
        $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
        if($length == 126) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 8);
        }
        elseif($length == 127) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 14);
        }
        else {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 6);
        }
        $socketData = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
            $socketData .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
        }
        return $socketData;
    }

    function seal($socketData) {
        $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
        $length = strlen($socketData);
        
        if($length <= 125)
            $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
        elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
            $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
        elseif($length >= 65536)
            $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
        return $header.$socketData;
    }

    function doHandshake($received_header,$client_socket_resource, $host_name, $port) {
        $headers = array();
        $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $received_header);
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            $line = chop($line);
            if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
            {
                $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
            }
        }

        $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
        $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
        $buffer  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: $host_name\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host_name:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
        socket_write($client_socket_resource,$buffer,strlen($buffer));
    }
    
    function newConnectionACK($client_ip_address) {
        $message = 'New client ' . $client_ip_address.' joined';
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'chat-connection-ack');
        $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }
    
    function connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address) {
        $message = 'Client ' . $client_ip_address.' disconnected';
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'chat-connection-ack');
        $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }
    
    function createChatBoxMessage($chat_user,$chat_box_message) {
        $message = $chat_user . ": <div class='chat-box-message'>" . $chat_box_message . "</div>";
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'chat-box-html');
        $chatMessage = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $chatMessage;
    }
}
?>
```

The author did not reply.

Comment: I'd opt for [Ratchet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet) which has WSS functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you actualy use `$context` . You should probably use `stream_socket_server`  to create your master sockett and use `$context`.

Have a look at https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer/blob/master/server/webSocketServer.php
on how to use all this.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I do not use the $context yet - I don't know how to use it. It seems that there is no option (at least I didnt find any) how to use it with socket_create()

I can rewrite it with stream_socket_server() but dont know what else it will affect... 

Any idea how to use parameters with socket_create()? socket_set_option() doesnt seem to be enough...

Comment: I have no idea how to use $context with socket. That is the reason why I switched to using stream-functions instead of sockets, also forced by having to use ssl.

Comment: I'll follow your lead :) Thank you very much :)